# javascript change name of called function

Tags: javascript

Hi all im very new to javascript so please be gentle.
im mixing php with my calls and I have a slight issue.
I need to alter the function name that is called in an onclick event.

```
<div class=\"span4\" id=\"pass\">
    <button class=\"btn btn-block btn-large btn-warning\" id=\"bypass\" disabled onclick=\"pass(); return false;\">
        - 
    </button>
</div>
```

above is the div with the std call.
before this point some variables are set from another function call and I need to change the above call to "pinpass2() or pinpass3 etc.

```
function pincheck(id,type,lastid,pin){
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display=\"block\";
    document.getElementById('calc').style.display=\"block\";  
    var staffid = id;
    document.getElementById('bypass').onclick = function (){\"pinpass\"+staffid(); 
    return false;
};
}
```

the above is the function that should do it but i can't seem to get it working.
Any help appreciated.
p.s if i include the following into the pincheck function the desired staffid is diaplayed

```
alert(\"staff id\"+staffid);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the problem, but why do you have the **;** after the **}** at the end of the second to last line? At best, it's unnecessary.

Comment: The answers given to this question are fine but I'm wondering why you have separate pinpass1, pinpass2, etc. functions and whether they maybe contain lots of duplication... would it not be possible to make a single function pinpass(id) that takes `staffid` as an argument?

Comment: By the way setting `staffid = id` is not doing anything in this function; you could just refer to `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the onclick attribute the same way you'd change any attribute ?

```
var elem = document.getElementById('bypass');

elem.setAttribute('onclick', 'pinpass' + staffid + '(); return false;');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bVJnt/)

Comment: hmm this seems likely but gives an error something like invalid lefthand side in assignment.

Comment: @user1927512 - fixed that, I was to focused on the onclick property.

Comment: perfect thank you. to all the others that suggested help thanks too, I think my explanation was poor as i should have mentioned my calls were dynamic and therefore required the values to be changed based on previous interactions.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('bypass').onclick = pinpass2;
```

That should work just fine. `pinpass2` is already a function, you can assign it to `onclick` like any other object (yes, functions are objects in Javascript). So just change the `onclick` when you need it.

If you can't detect changes to the result of `staffid()`, then you should use a switch instead.

```
document.getElementById('bypass').onclick = function() {
    switch(staffid()) {
        case 1: pinpass(); break;
        case 2: pinpass2(); break;
        default: pinpass3(); break;
    }
};
```

Though most of the time you don't have to do this. Also, I'm not sure if staffid is supposed to be a function or a variable, but it doesn't change anything.

By the way, this way of attaching handlers is quite old. There's a more powerful one:

```
document.getElementById('bypass').addEventListener('click', pinpass2, false);
```

With that you can attach more than one function. To remove one:

```
document.getElementById('bypass').removeEventListener('click', pinpass2, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript functions are first class so you can literally just assign `pincheck` to another variable like this.

`var pinpass2 = pincheck;`

Now you can still call it like this

`pinpass(1,2,3,4);`

Comment: Thanks, but please explain how i can add the variable to the end.
i.e
    var pinpass + staffid = pincheck;

Comment: @user1927512 which part are you confused about

Comment: @user1927512: It would be `window.pass = window["pinpass"+staffid];` in your case.

Comment: @Bergi since you've figured out his issue you mind if I put that in my answer

Comment: sorry again im new but your example seems to be adding a variable to the pinpass function call and not changing pinpass() to pinpass1() or pinpass2() etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% from your question, but it looks like you are trying to call a different function based on the staffid variable. I.E. if it is `2` you want to call `pinpass2()`.

If this is a global function you can call `window[ 'pinpass' + staffid ]()` and it will call the function you want (if it exists).

EXAMPLE: if `staffid = 2` then `window[ 'pinpass' + staffid ]()` is eqivalent to `window[ 'pinpass2' ]()` which is the same as calling `pinpass2()`.

This works because all global vars (including functions) are properties of the `window` object, and properties can be accessed using a dynamically generated name and square bracket notation.